# GWT.log output to file

Tags: file, gwt, logging

Is it possible to redirect the output of GWT.log() from the development console to a file?  I need to debug a compiled GWT app and any logging or exception traces would be really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT.log is compiled out, there is no way to get access to it when compiled to production.

On the other hand, GWT now has support for `java.util.Logging`, which can, when compiled in, send errors to the server for use however you want. It also can print these logging statements to a in-browser console, such as a popup or Firebug/Chrome Inspector. See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Remote_Logging (and other sections on that page) for more details.

Keep in mind that unless you compile in full stack trace info, the exceptions will be very hard to read. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions#Emulated_Stack_Data for more info.

There is no way for a browser (without dev mode running) to write to a local file, for logging or other reasons. This is done for security reasons. Html5 might have support for some of these things, but they won't be supported in older browsers.